# Periodic extensions and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Consider the periodic extension $g$ of $f(x)=x^2-1$ where $x \in (0,1)$. Now suppose that $h(x)$ is a continuous function, does $h$ composed with $g$ have to be continuous? I don't think it should, because there are points missing from the domain of $h(g)$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: We know that $g$ is not continuous, since $$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$$ does not exist. (Why?) What happens if $h(x) = x$?

Comment: would it be possible to make h(g) continuous if the only restriction on h is that it is continuous?

Comment: @johndoe My counterexample shows no, since $h$ is continuous. If $g$ is continuous, then $h\circ g$ must also be continuous, though - the composition of continuous functions must be continuous.